# KeyError while executing Python Code

Tags: python, file, csv

I am getting below keyError while running my python script which import data from one csv,modify it and write to another csv.

Code snippet:

```
import csv

Ty = 'testy'
Tx = 'testx'



ifile = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'))
cdata = [x for x in ifile]

for row in cdata:
    row['Test'] = row.pop(Ty)
```

Error seen while executing :

```
 row['Test'] = row.pop(Ty)
KeyError: 'testy'
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, but without a small sample of `test.csv` it's hard to say **why** it's happening.

Comment: It simply mean that, that there is no key 'testy' in your csv. Check the csv. or if you don't mind, please give sample of csv file.

Comment: either there is no value with key `testy` or the case is different. check for this

Comment: test.csv is something like this

Comment: test1,,test2
test3,,test4
test5,,test6
test7,test8,test9

Comment: I dont see any key in csv only value. Where this key should be there in csv?  I am pretty new to python and csv stuff so sorry if my question looks silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your csv don't have a header, where the specification of the key is done, since you didn't define the key names. The `DictReader` requires the parameter `fieldnames` so it can map accordingly it as keys (header) to values.

So you should do something like to read your csv file:

```
ifile = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'), fieldnames=['testx', 'testy'])
```

If you don't want to pass the `fieldnames` parameter, try to understand from where the csv define its header, see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> The first record may be a "header", which contains column names in
>   each of the fields (there is no reliable way to tell whether a file
>   does this or not; however, it is uncommon to use characters other than
>   letters, digits, and underscores in such column names).

```
Year,Make,Model
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

You can put your `'testy'` and `'testx'` in your csv and don't pass the `fieldnames` to `DictReader`

Comment: Thanks Guyz for your help. Error resolved now after adding the field names as given in code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, there is missing `testy` on the first line of `test.csv`

Try such content in `test.csv`

```
col_name1,col_name2,testy
a,b,c
c,d,e
```

Note that there should not be any spaces/tabs around the `testy`.